# Generalization of Sylvester–Gallai theorem

Tags: convex-geometry

According to the Sylvester–Gallai theorem, given a finite number of points in the Euclidean plane, either:
1) all the points are collinear; or
\
2)there is a line which contains exactly two of the points.
\
Now, I want to know, is it possible to generalize these theorem as follows.

Given a finite number of points in the Euclidean plane and $k\geq 2$, either
\
1) all of them lies on the polynomial of the form $a_kx^k+\cdots +a_1x+a_0$; or
\
2) there exist a polynomial of the form $P(x)= a_kx^k+\cdots +a_1x+a_0$ which contains exactly $k+1$ of them.